# Inno Setup: Exiting when clicking on Cancel without confirmation

Tags: inno-setup, cancel-button

If a the user clicks on "Cancel", I want the installer to stop and exit, WITHOUT asking I want to exit or not.

Can this be done somehow? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

This is very easy. Just add

```pascal
[Code]

procedure CancelButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer; var Cancel, Confirm: Boolean);
begin
  Cancel := true;
  Confirm := false;
end;
```

to your ISS script.